# Understanding Format String Exploits

Tags: c, string-formatting, exploit

I'm learning various exploits and I can't quite get my head around Format String exploits. I've got a fairly simple program set up in an environment that allows the exploit.

```
int woah(char *arg){
char buf[200];
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, arg);
return 0;
}
```

I'm able to control the arg being passed into the function which will be how the attack will happen with the end result of the program running my shellcode and giving me root. Making the program crash is easy, just feed it "%s%s" and it segfaults. We want to do more than that so we feed it something like "AAAA%x%x%x%x%x%x%x". Looking at the program in gdb we look at the buffer right after the snprinf and we can see:

```
"AAAA849541414141353934....blah blah blah"
```

That's good! We can see see the A's on the stack as well as the 41s which is A in hex. But then what comes next? I get that the general idea here is to overwrite the instruction pointer with four bytes by having the address at the start of our string that we feed in.....and then somewhere along the line we have it pointing to our shellcode.

How would I find the address of the seip/return address to overwrite?

Comment: The A's you see are not on the stack. They are being printed because your format strings says so. The 41's are... Guide to which direction? What is the question?

Comment: Edited for clarity. I think the next step in this exploit is finding were the instruction pointer is so I could overwrite it with an address pointing back to my buffer. How would I find either address?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format string bugs - exploitation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052648/format-string-bugs-exploitation)

Answer (score 0):

When snprintf() is called, a stack frame - memory region - is created to execute it's function statements. However, before this happens, the compiler needs to know the previous caller of the function  - return point address. This address is included in the stack frame so when the stack frame unwinds, that is the function is finishing up its work, it has go back to that address so the program can continue to run. What you are trying to do is overwrite this address with your shellcode address. Research more on stack frames, ESP, EBP, EIP to get the idea.